# Create a new column from a dataframe object applying a formula in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe object in python as follows:

```
              open    high     low    last gMonth
date                                             
2017-01-02  0.7220  0.7221  0.7166  0.7184  Peter
2017-01-03  0.7184  0.7241  0.7183  0.7219   Jack
2017-01-04  0.7219  0.7287  0.7215  0.7283  Peter
2017-01-05  0.7283  0.7357  0.7273  0.7338  Peter
2017-01-06  0.7338  0.7355  0.7289  0.7301   Jack
2017-01-09  0.7293  0.7374  0.7289  0.7586   Jack
```

What I want to achieve is to add a new column, 'result', next to gMonth such that the value of this new column is calculated based on the past few rows of existing columns. For instance, the 'result' of each row is equal to the square root of the average open for the past 3 rows (current row inclusive). In other words, the value of result for 2017-01-09 should be [(0.7283+0.7338+0.7293)/3]^0.5, and the result for 2017-01-06 will be calculated with the same formula applied backwards.

I very much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Series.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rolling.html):

```
In [16]: df["result"] = df["open"].rolling(window=3).mean()**0.5

In [17]: df
Out[17]: 
              open    high     low    last gMonth    result
date                                                       
2017-01-02  0.7220  0.7221  0.7166  0.7184  Peter       NaN
2017-01-03  0.7184  0.7241  0.7183  0.7219   Jack       NaN
2017-01-04  0.7219  0.7287  0.7215  0.7283  Peter  0.848980
2017-01-05  0.7283  0.7357  0.7273  0.7338  Peter  0.850216
2017-01-06  0.7338  0.7355  0.7289  0.7301   Jack  0.853229
2017-01-09  0.7293  0.7374  0.7289  0.7586   Jack  0.854673
```

As you can see, by default this will give NaNs at the start when you don't have 3 values; you can set `min_periods=1` if you want to get a value even when you've only got 1 data point to average over.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas
df['Result']=pd.rolling_mean(df["open"],window=3)**0.5
```

if you need more information about the rolling function .
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.rolling_mean.html